# Should a message system use enum, string, or #define?

Tags: c++

In terms of a message system for a game, or in general, in C++, which of these three is better? An enum feels best but I think it would mean newer classes could not really contribute.  Strings seem nice for scripting advantages but I'm worried about the overhead. Integer defines feel a bit Cish.

Thanks

Comment: Could you be more...  Specific?  What do you mean by "message system"?  A way to pass messages between players?  Between threads?  Between computers?

Comment: @Nemo I'm asking how I should define them, like WM_KEY_DOWN

Comment: And I am asking what you mean by "message system".  What kinds of messages?  Between what kinds of entities?  Your question is currently so vague as to be meaningless...  You need to describe your specific application in _much_ more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on what you are trying to do, what kind of data is in the messages (variable vs fixed-length), frequency of messaging, size of messages, etc. For example, I have seen messaging systems that use `struct` and `union` to package low level messages.

There is no one *right* way to do it, at least not without more information.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you make a Message class? This could contain a string to identify the message, an integer id, etc. This way you get the best of both systems. You could even have subclasses for different types of messages.

Comment: Yes - every time I have tried to use structs/unions, I eventually end up finding that I need a method, if only to textify the message for debugging purposes.  An enum member to identify the message is fine for me, along with an array of const strings to textify them, though it is a bit of a pain to keep them up-to-date as new messages are defined during development.

Answer (score 0):

National Instruments Libraries and many other board level interface programs use #define for industry standards errors.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, stay away from `#define` for simple constants.  It doesn't play well with namespaces.  Instead, use an `enum` or just a `const` variable in an appropriate namespace.  Either of these is typesafe and properly scoped.

There are some things only `#define` can do, but avoid it when there's another way.